# Selenium can't find element by name or id (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Consider:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import os
from selenium.webdriver import chrome

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://nmcunited.me.showenter.com/%D7%9C%D7%94-%D7%9C%D7%94-%D7%9C%D7%A0%D7%93.html")
driver.implicitly_wait(15)
christmasTag = driver.find_element_by_id('f_2561406_1')
christsmasTag.click()
driver.close()
```

I used the Python code above in order to practice on some basic Selenium operations.

I couldn't find any element, neither by name nor by id. No matter what I tried, I always got the same error, which stated that the element I'm looking for doesn't exist (the idea was to press one of the buttons, if it matters...).

This is a part of the HTML code of the website:

```html
<!-- Main page -->
<td
valign="top">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<!-- Page Content -->
<!-- Page Content -->
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
  <!-- The form -->
  <td valign="top">
  <form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="/site/form/sendForm.asp" OnSubmit="return CheckSubmit();" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <!-- Form Field List -->
  <table id='sop_form_594602' class='sop_all_form' align="center" border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0"
  >
  <tr>
  <td style="color:;" class="changeText14">
    <span style="font-weight:bold;">באיזה חג מפוטר ראין גוסלינג?</span><br>
    <input type="radio" name="f_2561406" id="f_2561406_0" value="1. חג הפסחא" class="rachbox" checked>
    <label for="f_2561406_0">1. חג הפסחא</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="f_2561406" id="f_2561406_1" value="2. חג המולד" class="rachbox">
    <label for="f_2561406_1">2. חג המולד</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="f_2561406" id="f_2561406_2" value="3. סליבסטר" class="rachbox">
    <label for="f_2561406_2">3. סליבסטר</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="f_2561406" id="f_2561406_3" value="4. חג ראש השנה" class="rachbox">
    <label for="f_2561406_3">4. חג ראש השנה</label>
    <br>
  </td>
</tr>
```

[This is the said website](http://nmcunited.me.showenter.com/%D7%9C%D7%94-%D7%9C%D7%94-%D7%9C%D7%A0%D7%93.html) (broken link)

By the way, this is the first program that uses Selenium I'm trying to run. Is there a possibility that I need to change some settings or that I need to install something else?

Comment: Could you please check and update the broken link?  The page may have moved elsewhere...

Comment: But this HTML is not [well-formed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_element). There is very little in terms of HTML end tags.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The items you are trying to find are inside of an iframe. You need to switch the context of the webdriver to the frame first.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
from selenium.webdriver import chrome

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://nmcunited.me.showenter.com/%D7%9C%D7%94-%D7%9C%D7%94-%D7%9C%D7%A0%D7%93.html")
driver.implicitly_wait(15)
frame = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.tool_forms iframe')
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
christmasTag = driver.find_element_by_id('f_2561406_1')
christmasTag.click()
driver.close()
```

Comment: i tried that and it doesent work.
i got the same error: "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"f_2561406_1"}
  (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.99)"
by the way, what did you mean when saying that the elements are inside of an iframe?

Comment: I believe you you are looking for `frame = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[id*="IFwinEdit_forms_dr4r3_forms"]')` @GalBar-nahum

Comment: @Guy i tried it as well.
it has the same outcome, still the same error... :(

Comment: Look at the DOM, you can see the elements are inside of a separate `iframe` element. Using the code I provided in my answer, it works fine for me. Have you tried just copy and pasting what I put?

Answer (score 0):

Verify whether the "id" is getting changed and generated dynamically by refreshing the page. If it is the case then use the below XPath expression to find the element:

```
"//input[@value='2. חג המולד']"
```

Comment: it doesent work as well.
by the way, when i ran the code (with some changes of course) on the home page of google, it did find the elements.