# selenium NoSuchElementException when trying to fill username

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

tried to look up the answer here but couldn't solve my problem hope you guys can help, this is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from pathlib import Path
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui

download_path = Path("mypath")

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
    "download.default_directory": str(download_path),
    "download.prompt_for_download": False,
    "download.directory_upgrade": True,
    "safebrowsing.enabled": True
})
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\chromedriver.exe",options=options)
wait = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
def schwabLogin():
    driver.get("https://www.schwab.com/public/schwab/client_home")
    login = driver.find_element_by_name("LoginId")
    login.clear()
    login.send_keys("fakeuser")
    login.submit()
    wait.until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_id('login-passwd'))
    pwd = driver.find_element_by_name("Password")
    pwd.send_keys("fakepass")
    driver.find_element_by_id("LoginText").click()

schwabLogin()
```

this is the error I get:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="LoginId"]"}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium can't find element by name or id (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41131630/selenium-cant-find-element-by-name-or-id-python)

Comment: no... as you can see from @sameer answer I have additional problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `iframe` is present on the page, so you need to first switch to that iframe and then operate on the elements.
You can do it like:

```
def schwabLogin():
    driver.get("https://www.schwab.com/public/schwab/client_home")

    #Switch to iframe here
    driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id('lms-home'))


    login = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "LoginId")))
    login.click()
    login.send_keys("fakeuser")
    pwd = driver.find_element_by_name("Password")
    pwd.click()
    pwd.send_keys("fakepass")
    driver.find_element_by_id("LoginText").click()
```

You need to add the following imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: how do i find what is the iframe? or should I just write 'iframe'?

Comment: Please use the line of code that i have mentioned in the answer, it would work.

Comment: @bikoman57 i have added explicit wait in the answer, please pick the new answer and add the imports that i have mentioned in the updated answer.

Comment: copied your import and new wait command, now I am getting TimeoutException.

Comment: @bikoman57 have identified the iframe by its `id` now. Please pick the updated answer. It would definitely work (have tested it on my own)

Comment: now it insert the username but not the password. with no error just seem to skip over the password and press Log in

Comment: @bikoman57 because you need to first click on the pwd field and then input the value in it. I have update that in the answer. Please pick the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I checked https://www.schwab.com/public/schwab/client_home and it seems that the Login ID input field is not loaded immediately to the DOM tree when the browser loads the page.

Selenium driver could be so fast that it throws NoSuchElementException before the element is loaded.

Could you try putting a wait before locating the element:

driver.get("https://www.schwab.com/public/schwab/client_home")
**DRIVER WAIT**
login = driver.find_element_by_name("LoginId")

Selenium wait: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Hopefully this solves your problem :)