# Selenium Webdriver (Python) - Unable to locate ANY element of the webpage

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to navigate this webpage (https://www.msci.com/end-of-day-data-country), select some options from the dropdown menu and then further click on each country's name to go to a different webpage.

However I have been unable to locate anything from the page, searching by id, class, name, xpath and also unable to find or switch to any iframe.

At first I tried to find the Currency dropdown by copying its xpath:

```py
!pip install selenium
!apt-get update # to update ubuntu to correctly run apt install
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)

# Example searches
wd.get("https://www.msci.com/end-of-day-data-country")
wd.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='templateForm:selectOneMenuCategoryCountryCurrency']")
wd.find_element_by_css_selector("#templateForm\:selectOneMenuCategoryCountryCurrency")
```

I then found the problem can be linked to iframes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41131630/selenium-cant-find-element-by-name-or-id-python/41133765), but tried and failed to find iframes:

```py
wd.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")
```

How to properly access content in this page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I navigate to your URL I don't get your expected page. I get redirected to an "accept terms and conditions" page:

[image]

You'll get this with selenium because when you start selenium it creates a new user profile every time. That means your settings, your cookies and your cache is not used.

You can simulate this behaviour by starting a new incognito session.

Before you can find any of your object you'll need to press Accept on the cookies message and accept the T&Cs page.

I also suggest you add some synchronisation to your page. You can read about selenium's wait strategies [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html).

Then, you are right about iframes in your script. You can either do:

```
wd.switch_to_frame(<locator>)
```

Or (recommended) use the more stable wait + expected condition;

```
WebDriverWait(wd, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((<locator>))
```

Putting it all together gives you this:

```
wd.get("https://www.msci.com/end-of-day-data-country")

# Accept cookies
cookieAccept = WebDriverWait(wd, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[contains(@class,'gdpr-allow-cookies')]")))
cookieAccept.click()

#wait for the message to dribble off screen....
WebDriverWait(wd, 10).until_not(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[contains(@class,'gdpr-allow-cookies')]")))

# Accept on Ts&Cs
ConditionsAccept = WebDriverWait(wd, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[contains(@class,'accept-btn')]")))
ConditionsAccept.click()


#switch to the frame:
WebDriverWait(wd, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe[contains(@src,'IEIPerformanceCountry.jsf')]")))

#get the currency object as per your code
currency = WebDriverWait(wd, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='templateForm:selectOneMenuCategoryCountryCurrency']")))
print(currency.text)
```

As I'm just printing the currency output, I get:

> USD  EUR  Local  GBP  JPY  CAD  CHF  HKD  AUD  MXN

Finally, when you're done with your frame and returning to the "main" page/frame use:

```
wd.switch_to_default_content()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! When I try to execute your script though, I get: "ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (295, 654)(Session info: headless chrome=85.0.4183.83)" at line cookieAccept.click()

Comment: Edit: problem above was solved by adding a longer waiting time

Answer (score 0):

I have some suggestions for you

- first of all, I really suggest you remove the **headless** argument from **chrome Option** in order to see what is happening. maybe some popup or notification prevents you from accessing your element.
- moreover, you need to access the web page with `wd.get("https://www.msci.com/end-of-day-data-country")` first that I'm sure you know it
- finally, the currency dropdown ID is clear. so you can easily get it. but you may notice that some elements are hard to interact with. so it is a good practice to utilize some JavaScript to pave the way. check this out:

  ```
   curr_drop_down= wd.find_element_by_id("templateForm:selectOneMenuCategoryCountryCurrency")
   wd.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", curr_drop_down)
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! Indeed I forgot the wd.get line in my question but I did use it of course. However, did you actually try the code you show ? I of course tried the same line but it fails