# Using python and chromedriver, how to click on a specific button of a pop-up window when I cant find his ID?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a code in python that uses selenium chromedriver to reach a webpage and collect some data but I want to solve a issue related with a pop-up window. For example, if you go to this webpage ***https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BAC?p=BAC*** you will get two pop-up windows. One is for the acceptance of the collection of personal data (image below) and this I can handle well with the following code:

```
...
# Go to the website:
driver.get(main_url)
# Click accept button
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "agree").click()
...
```

[image]

The second one (image below) however I'm not being able to dismiss. I want the code to click on the "Maybe later" button but I cant find the button ID. Can someone help me?
[image]

Comment: Could you try and find the element by XPath? 
`find_element(By.XPath, "//*[@id="myLightboxContainer"]/section/button[2]"`


Also, you probably need to wait until the element is clickable. Look here for more info: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41131630/selenium-cant-find-element-by-name-or-id-python)

Comment: you might have to use sikuli library

Comment: Thank you @LucaZangari! It worked! How did you associated that id ("myLightboxContainer") to the pop-up sign in window? I can find the id on the source of the page but not any of the text (ex: "Maybe later" or "Sign in to save BAC", etc). That's why I was not able to develope a code to deal with that button..

Comment: You can right click the element on the page and click "Inspect". It should jump directly to the right element in de developer veiw. From there you can right-click the element to copy out the XPath @rcmv.